# There is a problem that only No is returned even if Yes / No is set for Catalog Input Type for Store Owner in Attribute Properties

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, attributes, magento2.2.6

The selectable products and simplified products were saved with Yes.

No was output when acquiring the corresponding attribute code on the front end.

The following is the code written when getting the attribute value.

```
$child->getResource()->getAttribute('request_to_purchase')->getFrontend()->getValue($child);
```

My environment is as follows.

- Magento 2.2.6
- PHP 7.1

I do not know the cause.

please tell me.

**Properties**
[image]

**Storefront Properties**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you already have enable/disable(Yes/No) for the individual products. You need to run the following command:

```
bin/magento indexer:reindex
bin/magento cache:flush
```

I also have tested it on the magento ver. 2.2.6. See attached screen

[image]

I am not sure where you are reffering to see Yes/No value on frontend.

Comment: I updated the index and cache, but the output information does not change.

Comment: Please provide the problem in greater detail along with screenshot. Which magento version you are using etc.

Comment: Detailed information has been added.